# Rails search form in different controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Okay say I have a simple search form for Projects records like in the railscast found here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form?autoplay=true

Can you put the form_tag for the search in a different view other than the projects index.html?  Like in a static_pages controller type of deal view?  And how could you redirect to the projects index.html view after submitting the search in such a case?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can put the form anywhere as long as you also put the necessary logic in the loaded controller. Put some code in the post. Make it easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code wherever you want to add search functionality.

```
<% form_tag projects_path, :method => 'get'  do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Changes needed in your controller only. Try render view instead of redirect and you are done.

```
def index
  @projects = Project.search(params[:search])
  render `projects/index`
end
```